# CSS and Page download speed

Tags: css, download

my site seems to be downloading very slowly.  I recently changed the CSS and HTML to improve the layout, but I think I might have messed it up somehow.

Can anyone give me feedback on things I could do to speed it up?

Thanks.

[www.aerlawgroup.com](http://www.aerlawgroup.com)

Comment: who is voting down my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are many online Web Optimization sites that you can use.**

I've attached some optimized results for your page.

**From http://www.webpagetest.org/**
[See The Result](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/131228_GZ_75C/)

and you can use **Google Page Speed [Link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)**

Simply, I would suggest one thing based on your page design and the code is..., use CSS Simplify Tool and the HTML Symplify Tool. It reduces the Page Loading time dramatically. and as well as some Image Compression Tool too.

One thing that really reduces the page speed is Flash contents or Images. so be focus on that primarily

- http://csslint.net/ for linting
- http://csscomb.com/ for ordering attributes
- http://prefixr.com/ for adding browser prefixes

Comment: Thanks. It shows I have a 8.9s download speed.  But I can't figure out why it's so slow.  It used to be 3.8s.

Answer (score 0):

There are many many factors that come in play with a slow page besides CSS/HTML. The size of the images, whether they are optimized, how fast the server delivers, caching, etc...

I would recommend using Google PageSpeed Insights or similar service - they show you a lot of info.

Go to https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

**Edit:** Your URL loads this JS file which has an anonymous function that runs again and again:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/scripts.hellobar.com/bfa7653204b92054d559e0d8dd1ba2dd6fbdc183.js

You can view for yourself by using a web inspector - I am in Safari 7 and under Timelines on the Inspector panel - select "Layout & Rendering" from leftside menu and reload page. You can see that the HelloBar is doing some kind of adjusting over and over.

Comment: I did.  I'm going through those results now.  I'm just wondering if there's anything obvious to an experienced CSS programmer that I might have missed.  Thanks.